# How to create a patch/update (i.e. update an object) request in Django test client?

Tags: django, tastypie, django-testing

I am using Django 1.5. and django-tastypie

I am testing a use case where, first I have to create an object and then update that object via rest api.
e.g.

```
class FooTest(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['df_fixtures1.json']

    def setUp(self):
        print "SETTING UP?"
    def tearDown(self):
        print "Tear Down"
    def test_foo_delete(self):
          member1 = Client()
          member1.login(username='member1',password=test_password)
          response = member1.post('/fooapi/api/foo/?format=json', json_data, content_type="application/json") #**This creates the foo object**
          META =  {'X-HTTP-Method-Override':'PATCH'}
          response123 = member1.put(response['location'],
                        '{"isActive":0}', 
                       content_type="application/json", META = META    
                       ) **#This gives a 501**
```

The second request gives 501 error. On the server side there is a def obj_update i.e. a method to handle the update/patch request. 
What is the best way to update the object using Django client for rest api.

Comment: Have you tried with [`mock`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html)ing `obj_update` ?

Comment: @Shaikhul I have not tried it. I am not very familiar with mock.

Comment: Try that, you can mock/patch the `obj_update` with your expected behavior using `mock`

Comment: @shaikhul the problem is on client side. i.e. I am not able to reach the correct def of the rest api. Will mocking the backend/server work ?

Comment: I see, as you are getting 501 ( which means server does not recognize the request method), are you sure you implemented the `put` method ?

Comment: @Shaikhul yes I have. It works via javascript i.e. ajax. It is not working when I am writing uni test cases. As is the case above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85126/discussion-between-shaikhul-and-akash-deshpande).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the "PATCH" method is available from django 1.6 onwards this can be used as a hack on Django 1.5

```
response123 = member1.put(response['location'],
                        data = data, 
                        content_type="application/json",
                        **{'REQUEST_METHOD':'PATCH'}
                       )
```

This will change the method from put to PATCH. Hope this helps someone else.